# Template name for the user login block

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have been trying to create a template to control the user login block given in Drupal 7.  I've referred to the [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) documentation page and have tried block--user-login.tpl.php, block--user.tpl.php and am getting no love.
What is the template name for the user login block?.

Comment: Ok, figured this out (with some help) The actual template name is block--user--login.tpl.php (need two dashes between each)

Comment: You should write that as answer, and accept it. It doesn't increase your reputation, but it increase the number of answered questions, which is one of the parameters they check when they decide if this site can continue. If you this, I will up vote your question. `:-)`

Comment: Didn't I answer this in IRC?

Comment: yep. you sure did. I posted this before that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I answered this in IRC, I'll rewrite the answer.

block--user--login.tpl.php

The easiest way to find all of the possibilities for naming template files is to put `print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);` at the end of your theme's `template_preprocess_HOOK()`. Doing so works great for block, node, page...